# groupOfNames missing in OpenLDAP installation

Tags: openldap, raspbian

Using groupOfNames on one of my servers for LDAP Authentication, I wanted to move openLDAP to a raspberry pi for testing. 
On the pi there is no "groupOfNames" available.
So I am wondering if this might be due to the package installed or something else.
Where would I have to search to find out if "groupOfNames" is available, and how could I add it to my OpenLDAP installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the schema not being loaded. Have a look for `groupOfNames` in `schemas/*.ldif` and load the schema that contains it.

Comment: Finally found the issue. It was not openLDAP causing the issue. There was a xml-Template file missing in phpldapadmin on the raspbian package. Definitly didn't think of that, hence the unclear question. Will accept answer since it led me the right way. Thanks!

Comment: would be nice if you posted an answer. Having the same issue and looks like its the template in php admin probably. What xml did you add and where? Were there any other files you needed to load?